# In Eclipse, I've already imported a JAR library for Java, but why do I get errors when I use the import statement?

Tags: java

I want to use all the functions under org.apache.hadoop.fs, but I keep getting errors when I try to import it. The error message is in the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjMuX.png)

I hope to be able to reference it correctly. thanks

Comment: What's the content of your module-info.java?

Comment: just like 
module Test{
       requires hadoop.common;
}

Comment: List all your dependencies in that file or just delete it.